# create views.py to administration page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to make a page that can save a lot of students information for example when we want to add a new user/student  we should enter some required field..actually I can add and save a name,last name,NO, etc...but I can't save a many lessons for one student like this picture.
[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaMZU.png)

what I want is a view for my project . I try a lot Algorithm but I can't save to data base / admin page.
my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Students

class StudentsAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model =Students

class StudentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =   ["__str__","o_no","f_name","l_name","University","date","timestamp","update"]
    inlines = [StudentsAdminInline]
    admin.site.register(Students)
```

my model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Students (models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField()
    f_name=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)
    l_name = models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    o_no=models.CharField(default="",null=False,max_length=50)
    University=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)
    date=models.DateField(editable=True,null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    update=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

class Student (models.Model):
    student=models.ForeignKey(Students,related_name='items')
    Lessons=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    Code=models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True)
    Success=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

my forms.py

```
class students_form_admin(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Students
        fields=["__str__","o_no","f_name","l_name","University","date","timestamp","update"]


class student_form_admin(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=["Lessons","Code","Success"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Django Formsets. Take a loot at [Django Formsets.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/)

Or if you want to use only django admin, you should change your code to:

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Student, Lesson


class StudentAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model =Lesson

@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =   ["__str__","o_no","f_name","l_name","University","date","timestamp","update"]
    inlines = [StudentAdminInline]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Student (models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField()
    f_name=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)
    l_name = models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    o_no=models.CharField(default="",null=False,max_length=50)
    University=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)
    date=models.DateField(editable=True,null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    update=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

class Lesson (models.Model):
    student=models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name='items')
    name=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    Code=models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1,null=True)
    Success=models.CharField(default="",max_length=50,blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import Student, Lesson

class students_form_admin(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=["__str__","o_no","f_name","l_name","University","date","timestamp","update"]


class student_form_admin(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Lesson
        fields=["Lessons","Code","Success"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I'm going to suggest that you read through how to create a view. The Django website has a lot of information that is incredible helpful. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/) is the documentation for creating views.

As for saving to a database. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/) is the documentation on setting up and using databases with your project. [This link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/) will show you how to use models and objects to save data from your view.

The Django website has all kinds of information that can help you.

Comment: thank you..actually i code a views.py and i can save some information like name,NO. etc.. and i know the Django Official website but my problem is how to save many option to one thing..like i have 2 lesson and each lesson have a code_name and Success status... anyway 
Formsets will be helpful...